(1045, "Access denied for user 'myfirstDB_goprettywe'@'34.118.193.64' (using password: YES)")
I made a mysql database on filess.io and created a full stack application with flask on cloud replit.
I connceted my database to mysql workbench. And connceted database to my flask app using  command
engine = create_engine("mysql+pymysql://user:pass@some_mariadb/dbname?charset=utf8mb4")
my database name on files.io is myfirstDB_goprettywe. when i run my code on replit is it throwing error -
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (pymysql.err.OperationalError) (1045, "Access denied for user 'myfirstDB_goprettywe'@'34.118.193.64' (using password: YES)")
(Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/20/e3q8)
i am expecting my webapge should conncet with the database. Could anyone help me?
